# Need assistance replicating design in flutter code

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to design a Sliver App Bar in flutter. I have my design (below) but I am struggling to replicate it in flutter code. Would really appreciate it if someone can help me out with the code or explain how to do it.

Thanks so much!

[image: Design Image for Reference]

Comment: What did you try? Where exactly are you stuck? We are not a code-writing service, we help you with your problems. You have not yet explained what you problem actually is.

Comment: that's simple. Use an appbar with leading and trailing icons and the a body with column. Have two text inside your column and a SizedBox(height:12) in between your text to add spacing.

Comment: @Uni will that give me the same effect as a sliver app bar?

Comment: No. If you want to use Sliver App bar, you could use that instead of appbar. Just learn the basics of flutter. You'll be able to create that soon.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, you should try using flutter studio where you can drag and drop elements and the codes will automatically be generated.